# Failed to display Admob in small screen

Tags: android, admob

The admob work fine where the device's width 320 but smaller than that it will not display.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:id="@+id/layout_adsmob"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="10px"
android:background="#00ffffff"
android:visibility="gone" >

<com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adsmob"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="MY_AD_UNIT_ID"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
    ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR,TEST_DEVICE_ID" />
```

Comment: This is the expected behavior as per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/android/intermediate#bannersizes)

Comment: but i put smart banner, the banner did not show large in tablet and only show 320 only

Comment: any relevant LogCat messages?  If you're using smart banner, the ad needs the entire width of the screen.  Do you have any other parent elements of the ad that may have left or right margins?

Answer (score 1):

You set the root elements visibility to `gone`. Setting the visibility of any element in the XML file also hides the child-elements of the tag.

Just don't set the visibility at all. It defaults to `VISIBLE`, so there's no need to manually set it

If this is intended, and you want to keep it invisible until you load the ad, change the visibility programmatically:

```
someView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```